# Manifold of Infinite Cylinder?

Tags: general-topology

Is it correct to say that the surface of an infinitely long cylinder (of finite radius) is equivalent to the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Intuitively, the cylinder should be a dimension 2 surface, however, $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1$ will be a $2 + 1 = 3$ dimensional manifold. However, the infinite cylinder would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand… coordinates (x,y) on the surface would have x running from Negative to Positive Infinity (= R1 = R), but y only runs from (say) -1 to +1 (= S1). Thanks!